# Issue JavaScript (JS) retriving data from firebase using a loop

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database

I have a big issue when i'm trying to get values from firebase and update content from a part of the html code. For that I'm using a for to get the route to the data.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var db = firebase.database();  
            var pos = ['der','mid', 'izq'];
            var pl = 1;
            var dataT = ['sonido', 'mov'];
            for( var pl = 1; pl<4; pl++) {
                for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    var search = 'insti/planta'+pl+'/'+pos[i];
                    var srSn = 'pl'+pl+'-pos-'+pos[i]+'-data-sonido';
                    var srMv = 'pl'+pl+'-pos-'+pos[i]+'-data-mov';

                    db.ref(search).on("value",function(snap){    //WeMos1   
                        console.log(srSn);
                        console.log(srMv);
                        console.log(pl);
                        console.log(pos[i]);
                        sonido = snap.val().sonido;
                        mov = snap.val().mov;
                        console.log("sonido: "+sonido);
                        console.log("mov: "+mov);
                        document.getElementById(srSn).innerHTML = "Sonido = "+sonido;
                        document.getElementById(srMv).innerHTML = "Movimiento: "+mov.toString();;

                    }); //FIN WeMos1

                }
            }

        });
```

On the console output I get this:

> ```
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 123
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 341
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 672
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 312
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 511
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 622
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 12
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 331
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> VM5537:39 pl3-pos-izq-data-sonido
> VM5537:40 pl3-pos-izq-data-mov
> VM5537:41 4
> VM5537:42 undefined
> VM5537:45 sonido: 623
> VM5537:46 mov: no
> ```

I deduced that it only update the last var that I get. The result in the html is:
[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiSAR.png)

I expected to check every time that variables and print in a webpage. Here is the structure from the firebase:

[Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJg9I.png)

Comment: You probably don't want to use `on()` here, since it attaches a listener permanently until you remove it..  Use `once()` to get data a single time.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: I want to get it sync with firebase if is it posible

Comment: The problem is when I'm trying to execute the db.ref(searc)... part, it's not sync with the rest of the code and only update me the last var that I get. I want to update all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a closure/self-invoking function to capture the value of `srSn` and `srMv`, as explained in [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue) and [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript).

The simplest way to do that is to extract the code that interacts with Firebase into a named function and pass in the values of `srSn` and `srMv`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var db = firebase.database();  
    var pos = ['der','mid', 'izq'];
    var pl = 1;
    var dataT = ['sonido', 'mov'];
    for( var pl = 1; pl<4; pl++) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            var search = 'insti/planta'+pl+'/'+pos[i];
            var srSn = 'pl'+pl+'-pos-'+pos[i]+'-data-sonido';
            var srMv = 'pl'+pl+'-pos-'+pos[i]+'-data-mov';
            updateUI(search, srSn, srMv);
        }
    }
});

function updateUI(search, srSn, srMv) {
    db.ref(search).on("value",function(snap){    //WeMos1   
        sonido = snap.val().sonido;
        mov = snap.val().mov;
        document.getElementById(srSn).innerHTML = "Sonido = "+sonido;
        document.getElementById(srMv).innerHTML = "Movimiento: "+mov.toString();;
    }); //FIN WeMos1

}
```